# Python. Окончание ввода

Tags: python

Подскажите, как задать окончание ввода данных в Python при нажатии Enter?
Например цикл, при каждом обращении запрашивает данные, при нажатии Enter - выход из цикла?
Спасибо

Comment: В общем случае ввод данных через input завершается при нажатии "Enter". Приведите свой код.

Comment: окончание ввода данных в питоне и так уже задано через Enter

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

Например, так:

```
while True:
    data = input()
    if not data:
        break
    print(data)
```

Используется тот факт, что пустая строка в Python считается как `False`, а не пустая как `True`.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, тем временем сам дотумкал. Просто условие в цикле - While value. Идея та же)

Comment: @KN Так тоже можно, но понадобится лишнее присвоение переменной, которая проверяется. В моём варианте лишнего присвоения нет :)

Comment: @CrazyElf Зато есть целый if с break'ом. :)

Comment: @GrAnd А условие проверки ввода всё-равно должно быть. Если только `input` в конец цикла `while` поместить, а ещё один `input` сделать перед ним... Ну, так тоже можно, но, повторюсь - не люблю дублирование кода )

Comment: @CrazyElf Что-то вроде `do ... until` очень не хватает в таких вот случаях.

Comment: @CrazyElf можно использовать `:=`, конечно если python 3.8+

Comment: @Danis В Google Colab до сих пор 3.7.11, а я обычно в нём сижу. Так то да )